# If a list element matches 1st tuple element replace it with 2nd tuple element

Tags: haskell

I am given 2 lists:
- `list1` as a dictionary in a form of tuples:
`[("aaa", "bb"), ("d", "efg"), ("if found this", "replace with this")]`
- `list2` as a list of elements to translate: `["aaa", "efg", "zzz"]`

I need to return a list where elements from `list2` are replaces with tuples 2nd element from `list1` elements if `list2` element matches `list1` tuples 2nd element. In this example result list would look like this `["bb", "efg", "zzz"]`

How to do this?
I only started to learn Haskell only recently so syntax is my main problem. I think the function definition should look like this
`replace ::  Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [a] -> [a]`
and the function should do something like try ti find `list2` value in tuples if found keep value from tuple and recursively call function `replace`, if value is not found keep value from `list2` and recursively call function `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

list1 = [("aaa", "bb"), ("d", "efg"), ("if found this", "replace with this")]
list2 = ["aaa", "efg", "zzz"]

replace d = map (\k -> M.findWithDefault k k d)

main = print $ replace (M.fromList list1) list2
```